# Set a value in CKEditor 3

Tags: ckeditor

This probably is a very very basic question but i can't seem to find anything about it in the manual. All i want to do is set a value in textarea converted to a CKEditor instance.

I tried to pull out some javascript functions with NetBeans, but i couldn't find one that looked like setting a value. So I figured, lets take a look at the API description but nothing there eighter. So at last I've searched through the CKSource forums but strangly enough I couldn't find something there eighter.

Does anybody have some suggestions how to solve this very basic issue? (It's almost embarrassing to ask...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argh.. it was embarrassing indeed. You are able to simply put the contents between the `<textarea></textarea>` tags.

In the older versions (FCKEditor) you have set a value manually to the editor, I guess that's why I went searching through to the API;)

Answer (score 0):

And if you are calling it from php code, you can write below code

```
$ckeditor->editor('editor1',$content_data);
```

syntax

```
$ckeditor->editor('desiredfieldname', $desired_content_from_database_or_anything);
```